# Why does Powershell Out-Printer ignore `f (new page) in text?

Tags: powershell, printing, page-break

Iam trying to pipe some text to a printer and i need to split the content to multiple pages.
According to [this](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-esc.html) there is the control character **`f** to insert a form feed, which should only affect the printed document.

Simplified, my code looks like this:

```
"Hello page 1`fThis should be on page 2" | lp
```

It does not matter if i directly print this way or use a PDF printer - the text appears in one single line on a single page.

All other control characters seem to work fine.

UPDATE: I was wrong, `t doesn't work either

Comment: Confirmed that this happens to me with PowerShell 4.0.

Comment: update: `t is also not working. Am I missing something curcial here?

Comment: Had no luck with manual formatting so i tried Format-Table. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31555234/powershell-out-printer-breaks-format-table-column-layout